# Apache Axis 1.4 deployment failure

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, axis

I'm having a hard time with deploying Apache Axis 1.4 (though its pretty old, it is a condition that I use this). It seems Glassfish (I've tried even TomEE; error is the same)  is "ignoring" some classes, which ARE included in the classpath (axis.jar) of my project (it's primarily org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc) and I cant really figure out why.

I would appreciate and help.

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc
at ivectorbookingxml.PropertyDetailsResponse.(PropertyDetailsResponse.java:1017)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.TypeUtil.getMethod(TypeUtil.java:401)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.MethodDescriptor.getMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:339)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.convertEJBMethodPermissions(EJBSecurityManager.java:592)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.loadPolicyConfiguration(EJBSecurityManager.java:263)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.initialize(EJBSecurityManager.java:320)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.(EJBSecurityManager.java:199)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.factory.EJBSecurityManagerFactory.createManager(EJBSecurityManagerFactory.java:203)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainerFactory.getSecurityManager(BaseContainerFactory.java:64)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:60)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
... 38 more

SEVERE: Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:234)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc
at ivectorbookingxml.PropertyDetailsResponse.(PropertyDetailsResponse.java:1017)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.TypeUtil.getMethod(TypeUtil.java:401)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.MethodDescriptor.getMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:339)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.convertEJBMethodPermissions(EJBSecurityManager.java:592)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.loadPolicyConfiguration(EJBSecurityManager.java:263)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.initialize(EJBSecurityManager.java:320)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.(EJBSecurityManager.java:199)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.factory.EJBSecurityManagerFactory.createManager(EJBSecurityManagerFactory.java:203)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainerFactory.getSecurityManager(BaseContainerFactory.java:64)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:60)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
... 38 more

SEVERE: Exception while loading the app
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc
at ivectorbookingxml.PropertyDetailsResponse.(PropertyDetailsResponse.java:1017)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.TypeUtil.getMethod(TypeUtil.java:401)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.MethodDescriptor.getMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:339)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.convertEJBMethodPermissions(EJBSecurityManager.java:592)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.loadPolicyConfiguration(EJBSecurityManager.java:263)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.initialize(EJBSecurityManager.java:320)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.(EJBSecurityManager.java:199)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.factory.EJBSecurityManagerFactory.createManager(EJBSecurityManagerFactory.java:203)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainerFactory.getSecurityManager(BaseContainerFactory.java:64)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessContainerFactory.createContainer(StatelessContainerFactory.java:60)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:221)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:291)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:99)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:206)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:313)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Do you have `commons-logging` in your classpath? It seems that it can not initialize TypeDesc, because initialization of static variable of type  `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` fails.

Comment: Yes, I do. I use Maven and dependency graph is clear, so there shouldn't be any dependency problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for pointing to commons-logging, I've already figured out, how to work around it, though its pretty wierd. I've scoped the commons-logging dependency to "provided" and added it to the servers lib/ext folder => everything works. I would understand this issue if there were multiple logging.JARs on the server, but there were none, so I would still like someone to explain it to me :)